# How to upload multiple main functions to 1 GitHub repository?

Tags: c++, git, github

I want to upload my version of the solution of the book "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++" to GitHub, in a way that anyone interested can access the code and run it easily.

Assuming that 1 repository can hold 1 project only, and since the solution code for every drill or excercise of the book has to be an independent .cpp file/main function, how can I group all of the code in the same repository, and at the same time allow anyone, who clone or download the file, to run and debug independently? (...because there cannot be two main functions in one project right?)

Comment: A Git repository can contain as many files and directories as you want. How you organize them and what you consider as "one project" is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Separate folder for each solution could do the trick.

You can go even with separating using "one solution" = "one .cpp file" scheme. In this case build is assumed to be done without make file, by specifying .cpp file to the compiler. But it will create mess if some solution require multiple .h / .cpp files.

Answer (score 0):

My [misc-basile](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/) `github` repository contains *several* single source programs ([GPLv3+ licensed](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), for Linux), including `manydl.c` -which shows that Linux is capable of dealing with many (that is, more than a hundred thousands) plugins by dynamically generating them, and `sync-periodically.c` -which calls periodically the [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) system call.

You can do likewise for your single file C++ programs.

You could write your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) compiling each of them to a different [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable). Or use some other [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) (e.g. [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html)).

However, don't forget to document (in your `README.md`) what each of your C++ [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) is supposed to do, and how to compile and run them.

Read more about [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), about [operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/), about *your* C++ [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) and [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) (e.g. [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)) and other software development tools (e.g. [git](https://git-scm.com/), [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)).

Details are of course implementation specific.